# Calling windows command prompt and use find to check if a string is in a text file

Tags: windows, cmd, vbscript, find, errorlevel

I want to use:

```
Set cmdLine = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
```

Then I want to do something like:

```
check = cmdLine.Exec("%comspec% /C find /N "End of Report" D:\test3.txt)
```

But I am not very familiar with coding in the command prompt... so I don't really know what I am doing. But I want to search for a string of text in a .txt file and see if it exist or not... I don't really need a to know what line number it is found on or anything... just if it was found or not.

PS- I am going about it this way to avoid having to open the text file if the string isn't found.

I read that find has one of three %errorlevel%  responses.

0 – The string you were searching for was found.
1 – The string you were searching for was not found.
2 – This means you had a bad switch or your parameters were incorrect.

I don't really know what they mean by %errorlevel%  responses... but I am hoping to do something like"

```
if check = 0 then
    'do something
End if
```

meaning... If the string I am searching for is found... then do something...

Comment: Your line `check = ...` has got unbalanced quotation marks...

Comment: [`ErrorLevel`](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html) is a thing specific to [`cmd.exe`](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html). Anyway, why calling a command line via `cmd.exe` to find a certain string in a text file rather than using VBScript code for that?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use `FileSystemObject` and `InStr` on `Files`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was the solution i found that worked for my purposes.

```
Dim cmdLine As Object
Dim result As String
Dim SearchStr As String
Dim FilePath As String  

Set cmdLine = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
result = cmdLine.Exec("%comspec% /C Find " & SearchStr & " " & Chr(34) & FilePath & Chr(34)).STDOut.ReadAll
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.  It uses VBScript to retrieve all the text in a file as suggested in the comments above, and does a case-insentivie search for a specific search string.  Modify it as required:

```
Option Explicit

Dim objFSO : Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim objTextStream, allText
Dim searchTerm : searchTerm = "End of Report"

const strFileName = "D:\test3.txt"
const fsoForReading = 1

If objFSO.FileExists(strFileName) then

    Set objTextStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName, fsoForReading)
    allText = objTextStream.ReadAll

    if instr(1,allText,searchTerm,1) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Found"
    end if

    objTextStream.Close
    Set objTextStream = Nothing
End If

Set objFSO = Nothing
```